# Como invocar um tratamento de evento?

Tags: java, javafx, eventos

A ideia é simples: eu tenho um objeto do tipo `Node` e gostaria de invocar o tratamento do evento KeyEvent.

O tratamento não sou eu que crio, então não vejo outra alternativa senão fazer a invocação.

Tentei utilizar o método fireEvent(), mas não obtive sucesso.

Alguém saberia resolver isso?

Comment: Poderia colocar algum código, ou pelo menos uma representação gráfica do que acontece?

Comment: Infelizmente eu apaguei o projeto de testes e não tenho mais os códigos com as tentativas. Quanto a representação gráfica, não é algo definido. Estou tentando fazer um método genérico que recebe um Node e ativa o evento de teclado.

Comment: @EduardoToffolo Não entendi o que deseja. Poderia explicar melhor?